# In memory storage of blocks in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I need some suggestions regarding the below 
I have written a script and here is the algorithm below

```
Step 1: Get the RID's from file 1 and store that in "temp1"
Step 2: With the help of "temp1" get the corresponding blocks from file 2 and accumulate it
Step 3: With the help of the accumulated block, get the counts of each of the fields
```

Code

```
Step 1: zgrep -i XXXX **FILE 1**|grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*"|uniq|cut -d "=" -f2 > **TEMP 1**  
Step 2 : awk 'while (getline < **TEMP 1**){requestArray[$0]++;} close(**TEMP 1**); GET BLOCKS >> **TEMP 2**}  **FILE 2**(CODE is trimmed)
```

After Long time

```
Step 3: GET=( $(awk 'Get the necessary fields from temp 2' **TEMP 2**) )`
```

PROBLEM I AM FACING

The problem I am facing is the slowness in the program due to input-output operations. As you can see in step 1 I am an generating a temporary file TEMP 1 in step 1and in the step 2 the **TEMP 2 file is appended multiple times** and thus due to this huge IO operations my program is slow

Solution
The solution for the same is to make temp 1 and temp 2 as in memory variables

Suggestions needed
To make Temp 1 as in memory, I need to know **how to read the output from a terminal and store that in an array** .. Could you ppl please let me know how to do this.

Similar to this I need to store the output that has been got in temp 2 as an array...

Could you ppl help me regarding this. Thank you.

```
SAMPLE DATA
**TEMP 1**
RID 1= 472349723478923489
RID 2= 672349723478923489
RID 3= 772349723478923489
RID 4= 872349723478923489
RID 5= 972349723478923489
RID 6= 372349723478923489

**FILE 1**
asjdghasdh23712893712983712893qwsdhaksdhask **RID 1= 472349723478923489**

**FILE 2**
Starting of block 1
time
date 
hour
parameter 1
parameter 2
parameter 3
RID 1= 472349723478923489
parameter 3
parameter 4
parameter 5
Ending of block 1

Starting of block 2
time
date 
hour
parameter 1
parameter 2
parameter 3
RID 57= 3423423423423234
parameter 3
parameter 4
parameter 5
Ending of block 2

Starting of block 3
time
date 
hour
parameter 1
parameter 2
parameter 3
RID 3= 772349723478923489
parameter 3
parameter 4
parameter 5
Ending of block 3

TEMP 2 
block 1 and block 3 from file 2 as in block 2 RID is 57 which is not present in temp 1. So this will not be contained here
```

Comment: Or the problem is the way you are approaching the problem. Can you give some lines of file1 and file2, and the output expected?

Comment: I have edited the question. It is the problem I am facing rite now

Comment: I am afraid it does not make it any clearer.  Having sample data would help to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have provided some sample data .. Please have a look at the same

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{requestArray[$0];next};$0 in requestArray{print "Found"}' TEMP1 FILE2
```

Explanation:

Read `TEMP1` once at the start and store in an array. `NR` and `FNR` are variables used by `awk`. They are both incremented each time a record is read except `FNR` is reset on change of file.

An alternative method is to use a `BEGIN` block see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGIN_002fEND)

Answer (score 0):

Now, **because you want to eat spaghetti from your nose** with out suffering, we are going to read your mind
and guess what you want to do. We have two options, one, grind the spaghetti into a liquid, and two, open your
mouth.

That being said, here is **my guess to what the problem *may* be**
file1, is some kind of structured data, that holds a key-value pair called RID.
I do not know what it is, or what it does, or represents, but reading between the lines,
file2 has a corrisponding entry.

Now, file2 is also structured in some way, and it appears like there are some key-value pair grouped
into some form of structured block, and there are multiple blocks.

Now, the question is, what is kind of final result are we aiming at?
Reading _between_the_lines_, I am guessing you want the whole block , when a key-value pair of that
block, the RID key, matches a certain condition. Is this correct ?

**Then what exactly is the condition?**
My guess is that you want do something along the line of
SELECT WHOLE_BLOCK from FILE2 when RID of BLOCK exsits in FILE1

Then we have two options.
Assuming that your file2 is less then 9000PetaBytes, and that the number of entries are also less then what
a IEEE 52 bit fp can handle, store it in memory.

```
echo ""| awk '
function cmd( E, A, this,v){ A[0]=0;while((E |getline v)>0)A[A[0]+=1]=v;A["RETURN_CODE"]=close(E);}
function grep( o, re, p, B, this, a,v ){
 B[0]=0;if(o~"-v"){while((getline v < p)>0){if(!match(v,re))B[B[0]+=1]=v;}return B[0];};
 if(o~"-o"){while((getline v < p)>0){a=v;while(match(a,re)){B[B[0]+=1]=substr(a,RSTART,RLENGTH);
 a=substr(a,RSTART+RLENGTH);}};return B[0];};while((getline v < p)>0){if(match(v,re))B[B[0]+=1]=v;}return B[0];
}
function dbg_printarray(ary , x , s,e, this , i ){x=(x=="")?"A":x;for(i=((s)?s:1);i<=((e)?e:ary[0]);i++){print x"["i"]=["ary[i]"]"}}
function agrep( o, re, A, B, this, a, i,k ){
 B[0]=0;k=0;if(o~"-v"){for(i=1;i<=A[0];i++){if(!match(A[i],re)) B[k+=1]=A[i];}B[0]=k;return k;};
 if(o~"-o"){for(i=1;i<=A[0];i++){a=A[i];while(match(a,re)){B[B[0]+=1]=substr(a,RSTART,RLENGTH);a=substr(a,RSTART+RLENGTH);};
 };B[0]=k;return k;};for(i=1;i<=A[0];i++){if(match(A[i],re))B[k+=1]=A[i];};B[0]=k;return k;
}
{
    SAFETY_SINCE_WE_WALK_IN_THE_DARK=2000;
    input="file1";
    lookup_file="file2";
    output="output.data";
    we_died = 0;
    # Instead of -i option to zgrep, use [Aa][Nn][Tt] way of representation. 
    PATTERN = "[Rr][Ii][Dd]=[0-9a-zA-Z]*";
    if(for_gods_sake_we_are_scanning_normal_uncompressed_content){
        grep("-o", PATTERN , input , A);
    }else{
        cmd("zgrep -o \""PATTERN"\" \""input"\" ",A);
    }
    # Now, A has matching data. A[0] holds total. A[1] to A[A[0]] holds data.

    # Lets read lookup_file, block at a time. 
    # Since you did not give any specific caracteristics of file2, we can not optimeze in any way.
    # Oh well.
    while((getline v < lookup_file)>0){
        # Throw away head until we reach a valid block header
        if(v!~"^Starting of block ") continue;
        # We are inside block.
        blockid = substr(r,match(r,"[0-9]*$"));
        # get whatever data inside block untill we reach end
        c=0;
        delete B;
        B[0]=0;
        B[B[0]+=1]=blockid;
        while(((getline v < lookup_file)>0)&&v!~"^Ending of block" && c < SAFETY_SINCE_WE_WALK_IN_THE_DARK){
            B[B[0]+=1]=v;
            if(v~"RID"){
                # store it so we can later play with it
                B["RID"]=v;
            };
            c++;# We are fucked as the structure EOB was missing.
        }
        # we ither died, or end of block.
        if(c >= SAFETY_SINCE_WE_WALK_IN_THE_DARK){
             we_died = 1;
            break;
       }
       # We assume B has whole block. B[0] has total. B[1] .. B[B[0]] has data. B["RID"] has RID for fast reference.
       # Now, since the data format of file2 is not explained at all, I am guessing
       # A[n] == "RID=DEADBEEF"
       # and
       # B["RID"] == "RID=DEADBEEF"
       # holds true, which is totally unlikely. what if it is "RID          =     \t\t\t DeadBeEf"
       # so this is really impossible to guess as the OP is not even sure what format they are using.
       #   sub("^[Rr][Ii][Dd][ \t]*=[ \t]*","",B["RID"])
       # or something should be done so we can compare the damn thing.
       matched_block = 0; matched_idx = 0;
       for(i=1;i<=A[0];i++){
         if(A[i]==B["RID"]){matched_idx = i; matched_block=1; break;}
      }
      if(matched_block){
         # This block in B[] also matches A[matched_idx];
        # Do what ever you want to do with it.
        dbg_printarray(B,"B");
        print "A["matched_idx"]=["A[matched_idx]"]";
        print "Have fun";
      }
    }
}'
```

I have to say, without a clear picture of what you want to achieve, on one is able to help you.
Next time, do not think you are te best person to come up with a logic.
In general, there are experets who specilize in creating logic, and most of us,
choose what fits our problems. Trying to *solve* a problem does not mean you have to re-invent the wheel.
Just discribe what you have, and what you want to achive. Chances are, someone aready has done it,
and most likely there is a whole framework and duct tape to glue things togather.